# How do I also specify a generic collection type for a generic class?

Tags: swift, generics

Say I am creating a generic class where I would also like to make the collection in which the generic members are stored in generic as well. What is the proper syntax in going about doing this? In an attempt to get across what I'm trying to do, by best guess is below:

```
class AdjacencyList<VertexType, EdgeType, VertexCollectionType: Collection, EdgeCollectionType: Collection> {
    var vertices: VertexCollectionType<Vertex<VertexType>>
    var edges: EdgeCollectionType<Edge<EdgeType>>

    init() {
        self.vertices = VertexCollectionType<VertexType>()
        self.edges = EdgeCollectionType<EdgeType>()
    }
}

class Vertex<VertexType> { ... }
class Edge<EdgeType> { ... }
```

Comment: where is `EdgeCollectionType` and `VertexCollectionType` coming from? Are they custom collection types or let's say `Set` or `Array` of respective types?

Comment: I was expecting to use `Array` and `Set` namely, but I believe the solution code I'm looking for would be able to accommodate any custom type that conforms to the `Collection` protocol and accepts one generic type parameter. Being able to somehow accommodate `Dictionary` would be neat, but since that requires two type parameters I feel it would be out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you are using custom collection types or whether you want to specify them when creating a new instance of `AdjacencyList`, you can get away with something similar to:

```
class Vertex<VertexType> {  }

class Edge<EdgeType> {  }

class AdjacencyList<VertexType, EdgeType> {
    var vertices: [Vertex<VertexType>] = []
    var edges: [Edge<EdgeType>] = []
}

let list = AdjacencyList<String, Int>()
list.vertices // [Vertex<String>]
list.edges // [Edge<Int>]
```

Alternatively if you want to be able to specify collection type every time, you can do something similar to this (the code is in Swift 3, so `VC.Iterator.Element` should be `VC.Generator.Element` and `Collection` becomes `CollectionType` if you are using Swift 2)

```
class AdjacencyList <V, E, VC: Collection, EC: Collection
    where VC.Iterator.Element == Vertex<V>, EC.Iterator.Element == Edge<E>> {

    var vertices: VC
    var edges: EC

    init(vertices: VC, edges: EC) {
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.edges = edges
    }
}

let arrayList = AdjacencyList<String, Int, Array<Vertex<String>>, Array<Edge<Int>>>(vertices: [], edges: [])
arrayList.vertices // [Vertex<String>]
arrayList.edges // [Edge<Int>]

// as long as Vertex and Edge are Hashable
let setList = AdjacencyList<String, Int, Set<Vertex<String>>, Set<Edge<Int>>>(vertices: [], edges: []) 
setList.vertices // Set<Vertex<String>>
setList.edges // Set<Edge<Int>>
```

Comment: You second code using the `where` declaration seems to be exactly what I was looking for. However, I am getting a syntax error with `_.Iterator.Element` while using Swift 3, but I see a lot of other iterator types suggested. Perhaps the type has been changed?

Comment: I actually composed the sample in Xcode 8 Swift 3 playground. Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 8.0 beta (8S128d)

Comment: Disregard, apparently the compiler was fine, it just didn't like the class sitting empty. Adding the member variables caused the error to disappear.

Comment: glad it worked, the syntax for this is a bit not trivial indeed :)